# How to use a string as a module name

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I am trying to write a plugin system for my node.js CLI application.
The app should get descriptions from .json files and the actual function from a .js file, all set in a specific folder.

The application checks this folder on startup and requires each .json file
Based on the json data, it loads a .js file containing *module.exports = {functions }*

How do I access these functions from the main file at another time (after user input, or after a 10 sec timer)) ?

```
function fakeuserinput(x, y) {
  console.log(math.divide(x, y));
  })
}
setTimeout(fakeuserinput(10, 2), 10000);
```

(secondary question: is there a better way than using eval()?)

main.js

```
//commands is an array of all .json files
commands.forEach(function(cmd){ 
  // eval(cmd.module) = require('./plugins/'+cmd.module+'.js'); doesnt work
  require('./plugins/'+cmd.module+'.js');
  console.log(cmd.name+'\n'+cmd.module);
  // console.log(eval(cmd.module).eval(cmd.name)(10, 2));
  console.log(eval(cmd.name)(10, 2));
})
```

math.js

```
module.exports = {
  multiply: function (x, y) {
    return x * y;
  },
  divide: function (x, y) {
    return x / y;
  },
  add: function (numbers) {
    return numbers.reduce(function(a,b){
      return a + b
    }, 0);
  },
  subtract: function (numbers) {
    return numbers.reduce(function(a,b){
      return a - b
    }, 0);
  },
  round: function (x) {
    return Math.round(x);
  },
  squared: function (x) {
    return x * x;
  },
  root: function (x) {
    return Math.sqrt(x);
  }
}
```

divide.json

```
{
  "name": "divide",
  "module": "math",
  "commands": [
    [
      "how much is (integer) / (integer)",
      "how much is (integer) divided by (integer)",
      "what is (integer) / (integer)",
      "what is (integer) divided by (integer)",
      "(integer) / (integer)",
      "(integer) divided by (integer)"
    ]
  ],
  "description": "Divide x by y"
}
```

I am able to load functions without knowing their name like this:
main.js

```
//commands is an array of all .json files
commands.forEach(function(cmd){ 
  console.log(cmd.name);
  console.log(eval(cmd.name)(10, 2));
})

function divide(x, y) {
  return x / y;
}
function multiply(x, y) {
  return x * y;
}
```

but I am stuck trying to get to the function when its in module.exports of another file.

code for json files -> array

```
var folder = './plugins/';
fs.readdir(folder, function (err, files) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Couldn\'t read folder contents: '+err.message);
    return;
  }

  files.forEach(function (file, index) {
    if (file.substr(-5) == '.json') {
      let path = folder+file;
      fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Couldn\'t read JSON file: '+err.message);
        }
        commands.push(JSON.parse(data));
        console.log('Command added: '+file.substr(0, file.length-5));
      });
    }
  });
});
```

error message:
ReferenceError: math is not defined

Comment: Yes, there's definitely a better way to do this without using `eval`

Comment: on a browser you could get the function with `window[cmd.name]`...  on a server maybe on `global`?

Comment: No, don't use `global`. The point of modules is to avoid using the global namespace entirely. I'm currently writing an answer that should be much easier to use.

Comment: i have tried global[]() but as I understand, this doesnt work with module.exports.
Couldnt get it to work while testing around with it.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts i am willing to do my own coding, no need to do it for me, but a push in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: Not 100% sure if this is what you’re looking to do, but take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-dir

Comment: @SteamDev It wasn't, but I think that could work, keeping it in mind as a backup option for now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my modified version of his code, that works for my use case.
Replaced foreach with a while loop (foreach cannot be stopped)
Replaced eval() with new RegEx() variable
Hope it helps someone else as well.

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const { resolve } = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const readdir = promisify(fs.readdir);

function load (path) {
  return require(resolve(process.cwd(), path));
}

function plugincheck (line) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    (async function () {
      var pluginfound = false;
      var argumentarray = [];
      const files = await readdir('plugins');
      const plugins = files
        .filter(file => file.endsWith('.json'))
        .map(file => load(`plugins/${file}`));

      var i = 0;
      var amount = plugins.length;
      while (i < amount) {
        var re = new RegExp(plugins[i]['regex'], 'i');
        var result = re.exec(line);
        if (result) {
          pluginfound = true;
          response.conlog('plugincheck', 'found match: '+plugins[i]['module']+'.'+plugins[i]['name'], 'data');

          const plugin = load('plugins/'+plugins[i]['module']+'.js');
          const fn = plugin[plugins[i]['name']];
          let rslt = fn(result);
          resolve(rslt);
        }

        if (result) {
          i = amount;
        } else {
          i++;
        }
      }

      if (pluginfound == false) {
        response.conlog('pluginloader', 'Couldn\'t find matching plugin for command: '+line, 'error');
      }
    })().catch(err => {
      response.conlog('pluginloader', 'Couldn\'t scan plugins: '+err, 'error');
    });
  })
}

setTimeout(simulate_user_input, 4000); 
function simulate_user_input () {
  plugincheck('root of 10')
}

setTimeout(simulate_user_input_two, 8000); 
function simulate_user_input_two () {
  plugincheck('10 + 2')
}
```